# How to serve static images from /tmp in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

How do you serve images from Apache that exist outside the document root?

I have a devops process that runs builds for a UI testing build, which generates screenshots and stores them to `/tmp/images`.

When a build fails, the screenshot identifies where in the UI the error occurs. So to help developers see the failure, I want my build server (running on Apache), to be able to serve these png screenshots so everyone can easily access them. Because the images are associated with build records that only last for a day or two, storing the images in `/tmp` is fine, and I have a separate cronjob for cleaning them out based on timestamp.

According to the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html#outside), to serve files outside the document root, all I need to do is add something like:

```
Alias "/images" "/tmp/images"
```

to my site configuration file. However, after adding that to the end of my `<VirtualHost>` tag, and restarting Apache, I still can't access any png files stored in `/tmp/images` from Apache, and it just returns "No Such Resource".

Apache's mostly just working as a proxy for a Buildbot server, so my site config file looks something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin sysadmin@mydomain.com

    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "admin"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
        Require valid-user

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)$
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
    </Location>

    <Location /ws>
      ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8010/ws
      ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8010/ws
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /ws !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8010/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8010/

    SetEnvIf X-Url-Scheme https HTTPS=1
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    Alias "/images" "/tmp/images"

</VirtualHost>
```

Why isn't Apache able to serve anything from `/tmp/images`?

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't Apache able to serve anything from /tmp/images?

Several possible reasons.

`/tmp` traditionally has been a shared space for all local services and users. Over the years it has also been a big source of security problems for all kinds of services. Symlink attacks and DoS vulnerabilities due to guessable /tmp temporary files are common.

That's why systemd introduced the [`PrivateTmp=yes`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=) setting.

> If true, sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` directories inside it that are not shared by processes outside of the namespace. This is useful to secure access to temporary files of the process, but **makes sharing between processes via `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/` impossible**. If true, all temporary files created by a service in these directories will be removed after the service is stopped. Defaults to false.
>
> *It is possible to run two or more units within the same private `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` namespace by using the `JoinsNamespaceOf=` directive*

IN other words, the `/tmp/images` that your devops process writes to can't be seen by apache httpd because it runs a in a namespace with a private /tmp.

Solution: write your images in  different directory, but not in /tmp.

Alternatively: have the devops process also run in a name space, where your join the name spaces with `JoinsNamespaceOf=`

There may be other reasons as to why Apache httpd can't access `/tmp` , selinux, apparmor etc.

---

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8010/

Alias "/images" "/tmp/images"
```

The [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive may have precedence over the `Alias` directive.

You might need to do for /images as you already did before with /ws, exclude that path from the ProxyPass /

```
Alias "/images" "/tmp/images"
ProxyPass /ws !
ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8010/
```