# File not found even though it exists on server

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I added a `.crt` and `.pem` file to `/tmp/certs` an ran `chmod 777 <filename>` on each of them.

Now when I attempt to run my service I get this error:

> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com systemd[1]: Starting Nginx Hosted App - myadminui...
> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com nginx_myadminui[21396]: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/tmp/certs/my_admin.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/tmp/certs/my_admin.crt','r') error:2...file:no such file)
> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com nginx_myadminui[21396]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx_myadminui.conf test failed
> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com systemd[1]: myadminui.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Nginx Hosted App - myadminui.
> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com systemd[1]: Unit myadminui.service entered failed state.
> Sep 06 13:33:25 vu89.bdom.com systemd[1]: myadminui.service failed.
> Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

I double checked permissions on the files and that I had no typos in either the file names or my config. What would be causing this?

Comment: One possible reason is the systemd `PrivateTemp` setting explained here https://serverfault.com/a/1109811/37681 - additionally using `/tmp/` and `chmod 777`   to store TLS certificates is a bad security design and might in itself already be the reason well designed applications refuse to start. (although you'd expect a more useful error message in that case)

Comment: I agree, as long as you do such a bad thing, the question is not on topic for serverfault.com. please note that question should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. share the output of `ls -la /tmp/certs/my_admin.crt` remind to move it to /etc/nginx and create a sub directory like `ssl` or `certificate` and 777 is also a bad idea for a file that needs only 644 or even 444 (chmod -xw+r)